# Emails to recipients are not being sent using docusign sender view api where status is changed to sent

Tags: python, flask, docusignapi

This is my sender view from where i create envelope as draft and open it in edit sender view and send it but recipients are not getting emails

```
 @app.route('/sender', methods = ['POST'])
    def sender1():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            filename1 = pdf2.save(request.files['file'])
            subject = request.form['subject']
            body = request.form['body']
            path1 = pdf2.path(filename1)
            url1 = pdf2.url(filename1) 
            remoteFile1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url1).read()
            login_information = client.login_information()
            signers = [
                    models.Signer(
                        email=email,
                        name=name,
                        recipientId=1,
                        clientUserId=str(uuid.uuid4()),  # Something unique in your database.
                        emailSubject=subject,
                        emailBody=body,
                        supportedLanguage='en')]
            session['email']=email
            session['name']=name
            session['subject']=subject
            session['body']=body

            with open(path1, 'rb') as pdf:
                envelope = models.Envelope(
                    documents=[
                        models.Document(
                            name='document.pdf',
                            documentId=1,
                            data=pdf,
                            )
                        ],
                        emailSubject=subject,
                        emailBlurb='request for signing',
                        status=models.Envelope.STATUS_CREATED,
                        recipients=signers,
                )
                client.create_envelope_from_documents(envelope)

                url = client.sender_edit_view(envelope.envelopeId)
                models.Envelope(status=models.Envelope.STATUS_SENT)
                data=url['url']
                #data = data.replace('send=1','send=0')
                #print(data)
                return redirect(data)
```

This is the sender edit view to call api

```
def sender_edit_view(self,envelopeId=''):
        """POST to {account}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient.

        This is the method to start embedded signing for recipient.

        Return JSON from DocuSign response.

        """
        authenticationMethod=None
        returnUrl='http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback'

        if not self.account_url:
            self.login_information()

        url = '/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/correct' \
              .format(accountId=self.account_id,envelopeId=envelopeId,
                      )
        if authenticationMethod is None:
            authenticationMethod = 'email'
        data = {
            'authenticationMethod': authenticationMethod,
            'returnUrl': returnUrl,
        }

        return self.post(url, data=data, expected_status_code=201)
```

How can i send email to recipients using the api. i have tried using the create correct api also and tried to update recipients but emails are still not being sent.

Comment: Can't see which part sends email. By the way Flask has library for sending email you should probably try with it.

Comment: https://pydocusign.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo.html
I am using pydocusign for integration with docusign but in that i can't send email with this api call

Comment: What are you trying to do here? you are correcting an existing envelope?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the sender view, the problem is that the signer is being marked as an embedded signer (no email invite to the signing ceremony is sent).

Your recipients aren't receiving email invitations because you are setting the `clientUserId` attribute for them.

Setting `clientUserId` causes a number of effects:

- The signer becomes an embedded signer.
- An email invitation to a signing ceremony is not sent.
- The signer will sign via an embedded signing ceremony after you create one for them.
- The metadata of the value of the clientUserId setting is maintained with the signer for your app's purposes.

To solve the problem:

- Don't set the clientUserId attribute
- If you want to maintain metadata between the receipient record in DocuSign and your own app, use the recipient's `customFields` attribute.

  (This doesn't apply in your use case since you're using a uuid. But it may apply to other readers of this answer.)